# Wireless won't connect!

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, dell

I recently installed Ubuntu onto my Dell Inspiron 1545 laptop.

I can connect to the Internet via Ethernet, but wireless won't work. The prompt to put in the wifi password pops up, but when I put in the password, it simply says connecting and the prompt for the password comes back up! The prompt will come back up every two or three minutes, but the same thing happens.

I've tried to install drivers using Windows Wireless Drivers, but I can't seem to figure it out. My wireless card is an Atheros AR928X. This is my first time using Ubuntu.

Here is the output of the commands I've been asked to run:

---

1- Output of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller [11ab:4354] (rev 13)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:02aa]
    Kernel driver in use: sky2
--
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Atheros Communications Inc. AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002a] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Atheros Communications Inc. Device [168c:0200]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

---

2- Output of `lsusb`

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:63ee Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

---

3- Output of `nm-tool`, `sudo iwlist scan` and `iwconfig`

```
$ nm-tool

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            sky2
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        00:25:64:44:02:7D

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.90
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.254

    DNS:             192.168.1.254
    DNS:             75.153.176.9


- Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            ath9k
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        00:22:5F:C2:08:1F

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points 
    beau:            Infra, 00:26:B8:ED:E6:CC, Freq 2422 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 95 WPA
    verjee:          Infra, F0:D1:A9:14:03:7A, Freq 2452 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 32 WPA2


$ sudo iwlist scan
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 00:26:B8:ED:E6:CC
                    Channel:3
                    Frequency:2.422 GHz (Channel 3)
                    Quality=64/70  Signal level=-46 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"beau"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000024523a5e000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 36ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000462656175
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030103
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 2F0100
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A6C181BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1603001300000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180202F0050000
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP

                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD1E00904C336C181BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD1A00904C3403001300000000000000000000000000000000000000
          Cell 02 - Address: F0:D1:A9:14:03:7A
                    Channel:9
                    Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)
                    Quality=27/70  Signal level=-83 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"verjee"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000173491f180
                    Extra: Last beacon: 3636ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 00067665726A6565
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C121824
                    IE: Unknown: 030109
                    IE: Unknown: 0706434120010B1E
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AAD511BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 33027E9D
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1609080400000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 46050200010000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101010003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD0700039301730B20
                    IE: Unknown: DD0E0017F20700010106F0D1A914037A


$ iwconfig 
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
```

---

4- Output of `rfkill list all`

```
$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

---

5- Output of `lsmod`

```
$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
bnep                   17791  2 
rfcomm                 38104  0 
bluetooth             189625  10 bnep,rfcomm
parport_pc             32115  0 
ppdev                  12850  0 
snd_hda_codec_idt      60238  1 
arc4                   12474  2 
snd_hda_intel          32983  5 
snd_hda_codec         116477  2 snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13277  1 snd_hda_codec
joydev                 17394  0 
ath9k                 122028  0 
mac80211              475546  1 ath9k
snd_pcm                81124  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           13133  0 
snd_rawmidi            25426  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14476  1 snd_seq_midi
ath9k_common           13782  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              384090  2 ath9k,ath9k_common
i915                  479235  4 
uvcvideo               72249  0 
snd_seq                51594  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              28932  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14138  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
videobuf2_core         32212  1 uvcvideo
ath                    19436  3 ath9k,ath9k_common,ath9k_hw
drm_kms_helper         47459  1 i915
cfg80211              181041  3 ath9k,mac80211,ath
drm                   240443  5 i915,drm_kms_helper
psmouse                91381  0 
videodev              100265  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
snd                    62675  18 snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
videobuf2_vmalloc      12757  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13213  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
dell_wmi               12602  0 
coretemp               13362  0 
sparse_keymap          13659  1 dell_wmi
gpio_ich               13160  0 
wmi                    18745  1 dell_wmi
dell_laptop            17210  0 
microcode              18396  0 
dcdbas                 14099  1 dell_laptop
soundcore              14636  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         14109  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
serio_raw              13032  0 
lpc_ich                16993  0 
i2c_algo_bit           13317  1 i915
mac_hid                13078  0 
video                  19117  1 i915
lp                     17456  0 
parport                40931  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
ums_realtek            17929  0 
usb_storage            39720  1 ums_realtek
ahci                   25621  2 
libahci                26166  1 ahci
sky2                   53629  0
```

---

6- Modprobing

```
 echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
options ath9k nohwcrypt=1

sudo modprobe -rfv ath9k
rmmod /lib/modules/3.5.0-37-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k.ko
rmmod /lib/modules/3.5.0-37-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
rmmod /lib/modules/3.5.0-37-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_common.ko
rmmod /lib/modules/3.5.0-37-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_hw.ko
rmmod /lib/modules/3.5.0-37-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
rmmod /lib/modules/3.5.0-37-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko

 sudo modprobe -v ath9k
insmod /lib/modules/3.5.0-37-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/3.5.0-37-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/3.5.0-37-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_hw.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/3.5.0-37-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_common.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/3.5.0-37-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/3.5.0-37-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k.ko nohwcrypt=1
```

---

7- Output of dmesg | egrep 'ath|firm|wlan|network|wpa'

http://pastebin.com/ySLm71YN

Any and all help is welcome!

Comment: Please open the terminal(ctrl+alt+t) run the commands one line at a time: `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`
`lsusb`
`nm-tool`
`sudo iwlist scan`
`iwconfig`
`rfkill list all`
`lsmod` post the output at http://pastebin.com/ then post the link here. Thanks

Comment: @WildMan, please add the commands in more readable manner! :)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/1pc2fNBQ

Comment: @edwin I do not know how to make the commands more readable in comments, I have tried before and this is the best I came up with.

Comment: Sorry, should I enter the entire "sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep -e ath -e firmware | -e wlan -e wpa -e etork tail -n45" Or is each line a command that should be entered?

Comment: And beau is the network I am trying to connect to.

Comment: The whole command at once then post the results in your answer or pastebinit.

Comment: Inspiron-1545:~$ sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep -e ath -e firmware | -e wlan -e wpa -e etork tail -n45
[sudo] password for alek: -e: command not found


[1]+  Stopped                 sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep --color=auto -e ath -e firmware | -e wlan -e wpa -e etork tail -n45

Comment: Please post edit your answer with the results of: `dmesg | egrep 'ath|firm|wlan|network|wpa'`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/piihny4c  I'm not quite sure what's going on. Am I doing something wrong? (thanks for the patience)

Comment: Please copy and paste the command for accuracy, you have a typo. The tick marks before ath and after wpa must be there. Thanks

Comment: http://pastebin.com/aqBqTupp  Nothing appears to happen. Is this correct?

Comment: If it helps at all, there doesn't seem to be any wireless options when I click on the signal symbol in the top right corner.

Comment: Upon re-entering your previous suggestion in your answer, then re-entering your suggestion above, I managed to get this!

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ySLm71YN Hope this helps!

Comment: Have you tried the last suggestions I added to my answer? Go to network manager and make sure the wireless is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue with a RealTek RTL8188EEE wireless card and Ubuntu 13.04.  The quick solution was to just put in the IP of my Wireless Router, then change it from AES to TKIP-AES.  This kept the other systems on my wireless happy, and suddenly Ubuntu took the password and connected me with a reported 72Mb/s connection speed.

I couldn't do too much more since I was running from the DVD, making sure it works before I install.  I had seen suggestions of doing NDISWrapper and then rebooting - not gonna help with the DVD.

Hope this helps anyone else looking.  Probably too late to help the original person posting, but maybe it will help someone else.  If you can't do TKIP-AES, try going from AES to just TKIP.  That was suggested in another forum as well.

Comment: Yep, this did it for me. I changed my router to use TKIP instead of AES.

Answer (score 1):

Please copy and paste the commands for accuracy one line at a time:

```
echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf

sudo modprobe -rfv ath9k

sudo modprobe -v ath9k
```

Also it would be best to set encryption in the router to just wpa2 if you have that option by entering 192.168.0.1 or something very similar to those numbers in your web browser while having an ethernet connection, you may have to look at the documentation for your router for the exact numbers to enter.

Also try channel 1 or 11 in your router.

You can google the documentation for your router.
Please set your wireless settings in network manager to match the screenshots.[image: wireless settings][image: wireless settings]

You should also remove your connection in network manager and reset your router then reboot your computer.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/2fjtMnPy

Comment: Cant seem to find the router documents at the moment. Will comment if found. (Thanks for the help btw)

Comment: I would run the commands and see if that makes it connect then you can look up router documentation if needed.

Comment: Wireless still not connecting. I still can't find the documents. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I've gone through the entire answer, step by step, but the wireless won't connect. I think here is where I admit defeat. Thank you all, especially Wild Man,for all the help. I think I have to crawl back to Windows now... Again, thanks for all the help. You guys were awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have wireless-tools installed via *sudo apt-get install wireless-tools*

This will provide a better GUI to connect to existing wireless networks.

Try pinging any site, local computer or not, to test if it is working. You may get a specific error, which may mean that some of the settings are off.

Comment: When put into the terminal, it comes back saying that the wireless tools are already the newest version.

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using, and what desktop environment? (Unity is default, if you just installed)

Comment: Version 12.04 LTS. I am assuming that the desktop environment is "Unity" as I don't recall making any changes like that.